# How to auto fix formatting with ESLint and Prettier in Next.js project?

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier

Next.js has a guideline to integrate Prettier with ESLint [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/eslint#prettier).

1. Install the dependency.

   ```
   npm install eslint-config-prettier
   ```
2. Add prettier to your existing ESLint config.

   ```
   {
     "extends": [
       "next/core-web-vitals",
       "eslint:recommended",
       "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
       "prettier"
     ],
     "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
     "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
     "root": true
   }
   ```

Then, I have a `app/page.tsx` which has indentation and quote errors

```
app/page.tsx
const title = 'Heading';

const Home = () => {
         return <main>{title }</main>;
};

export default Home;
```

However the above errors are not fixed when I run

```
npx eslint --fix .
```

May I know what could be missing here?

Comment: I believe https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint will do this. However tbh you usually don't need it if you are using the prettier extension in your IDE of choice (vscode?) with "formatOnSave" set to true. The standard way of formatting the files not via eslint is just to run the prettier cli.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prettier addon for your IDE.

Or add following script to your package.json

```
"format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{ts,tsx,md,mdx,css,scss}\""
```

And of course, add prettier to your `devDependencies`.

Comment: Yes, that's work but what about running `eslint --fix .` in the command line without the IDE?